# How can I insert a certain character before and after another certain character?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a short Python 3 program that takes a Python 2 script, and fixes the way Python 2's printing function worked, and fixes it to make it work with Python 3. This is useful for some scripts that use Python 2, but the only issue is that there's tons of incorrect examples of printing according to Python 3.

Example:

Let's say I have a Python 2 script that looks like this:

```
print 'hello world'
```

I would want to use my program to convert it to this:

```
print('hello world')
```

So far, I have this, which strips the new lines, replaces the first instance of the quotation mark with an opening parenthesis, and replaces the second instance of the quotation mark with a closing parenthesis.

```
if "print" in ReadNextLine:
    RawInput = ReadNextLine.replace(" ", "")
    ReadyForFixing = RawInput.strip("\n")
    replaceportion1 = ReadyForFixing.replace("'", "(", 1)
    replaceportion2 = replaceportion1.replace("'", ")")
    print(replaceportion2)
```

Output:

```
print(Line1)
print(Line2)
print(Line3)
print(Line4)
print(Line5)
```

I was wondering if there was some way to insert a quotation mark after the first parenthesis, and before the second parenthesis.

Keep in mind that these outputs will be dynamic according to whatever the file that the user needs fixed inputs.

I plan on posting this project on Github. Let me know if you would like any crediting, since you may have technically collaborated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html

Comment: I would use a proper parser, you will miss a lot of edge cases. You can still use `.replace("(", "('")`, but the first idea is flawed. `print "double quoted string with a single quote ' inside"`, `print 'lol \' have fun \\\' parsing \' this' #followed by a comment with single quote : '`

Comment: If you're looking to convert python 2 to 3, I'd suggest to use a tool as khelwood suggested because it's a lot more tricky than your example with the escaping, strings with double quotes being escaped, `'this isn''t good'` and more variations. You won't have f-strings though otherwise `f'this {"wouldn't"}'`

Comment: @khelwood I did not know about this! I will scrap this project. Thank you!

Comment: If you are interested in tooling for changing code programmatically in general, take a look at the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module in the standard library and tools like [libcst](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).